# How can I get a glyph with holes(Python)?

Tags: python, ttx-fonttools

These are frameworks that I use:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import cv2
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import svgwrite
import json
from defcon import Font
import ufo2ft
from fontTools import svgLib
```

I have a svg file looks like the image below this sentence(The image is upside-down).

[SVG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuuhp.png)

I load this file and add to Defcon.Font like this:

```
glyph = font.newGlyph(name=korean_unicode_list[int(key)])
glyph.unicode = int(korean_unicode_list[int(key)], 16)
pen = glyph.getPen()
svg = svgLib.SVGPath("svg_files/" + str(key) + ".svg")
svg.draw(pen)
```

But after I export this Font object with ufo2ft, The glyph's hole has disappeared :(

```
ttf = ufo2ft.compileTTF(font)
ttf.save('myFont.ttf')
```

[After Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb3xV.png)

I don't know how to make holes at glyphs. I'm guessing that there is a solution at pen object and its methods, but there is no example about glyph with holes. How can I get a glyph with holes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution myself :)

I tested with Adobe Illustrator. I made '0'-shaped object and saved in svg file. When I export a font file with the svg file, there was a hole.

So I opened the svg file at PyCharm, there's a option name **'xml:space'**. If its option set to "preserve", svgPath can draw a path with holes.

I hope this article help you.